# Setting folder icon in Mac OS X 10.6 via command-line?

Tags: macos, command-line

I have a file.icns that I would like to set as custom icon for a folder. How can I do it from a script/command-line? The script is executed in the postinstall phase of a package installer. 
The language of the script can be any of the script languages supported by the package-maker (bash,perl,applescript should be fine).

Answer (score 1):

I found this (I did not test, but appears to be what you want):

http://hasseg.org/stuff/assignIconScript/assignIcon

Comment: The linked solution uses utils from the Developer Tools. But, since the script must be executed by an installer package, this cannot possibly work, unless those tools are distributed inside the package, which of course I'm not allowed to do.

Comment: @Valerio Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, but folder icons are supplied by an invisible file called `Icon` within the folder. Why can't your installer package install this file along with everything else?

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: I eventually found a little Obj-C script that does perfectly the job: http://www.macgeekery.com/sites/macgeekery.com/files/SetIcon.m

Comment: The `assignIcon` script doesn't work for me.  I get an error: `#<stdin>:1: ### /Developer/Tools/Rez - SysError 0 during read.`

Comment: Also, the macgeekery.com site seems to be down.... I'm surprised there aren't better answers to this!  It would seem to be a common thing people want to do.